# Isolate section of a string with repeated words

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to isolate (extract) a section from file paths and names. The problem I am having is its not working when a certain part of the file name is repeated.

File path/name can be one of the following:

```
/Make/Model/Year/image.jpg
```

or

```
/Make/Model/Model-Year/image.jpg
```

I am trying to extract

> `Year`

To make things even more difficult, the Year is formatted as both 2015 and 2k15.

I tried the following

```
/(?<=Model\/).+?(?=\/)/g
```

But this works on `/Make/Model/Year/image.jpg`, but does not work with `/Make/Model/Model-Year/image.jpg`, and instead selects `Model-Year`.

Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are doing or trying to achieve

Comment: can you post more examples of the input string and the desired result

Comment: I am trying to extract the 'Year' from file paths as described above, basically everything that comes after Model/, or Model-, but nothing after Year/. Or a simpler description would be everything either side of Year, but using Model as a marker/reference point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match optional `Model-` after `Model/` in a normal expression and reset it with `\K`. This would emulate variable-length look-behind:

```
Model\/(?:Model-)?\K.+?(?=\/)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SVbpa4/2

Comment: Hey Dmitry,
Thanks I had already tried the 'Model-' variation, but seemed to be the \K that I was missing!!